# How can copy string in the list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
list1=['a','b','c]
```

I wnat to copy every string in the list

like this

```
list2=['a','a','b','b','c','c']
```

```
list3=['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
```

but when I use this code

```
list2=[x*2 for x in list1]
```

I get

```
list2=['aa','bb','cc]
```

How can I change my code to accomplish my result?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `itertools.chain` along with `itertools.repeat`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
repeat_count = 3

list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(char, repeat_count) for char in chars))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Now that's a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

without using itertools, this could be done with nested list comprehension like below

```
list1=['a','b','c']

print([y for x in list1 for y in [x]*2])
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']

print([y for x in list1 for y in [x]*3])
# ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second `for` loop with the function `range()`:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']

[i for i in lst for _ in range(2)]
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```